# how to write sql command to get data like this

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the sql command to get top 10 model which highest available in car table on mysql database?

there are 2 tables related, model and car .Not mension about brand table yet for simplicity. display like this below.

```
> model                      car
> --------------------       -------------------------------------
> model_id| model_name|     |car_id|license_plate_number|model_id  |   
> ---------------------      -------------------------------------
>     0   | altis     |     |   0   |  xd-3203          |     1    |
>     1   | march     |     |   1   |  dj-2323          |     1    |
>     2   | civic     |     |   2   |  kk-9999          |     2    |
```

model_id is foreign key in car table.

assume there are  are 50  models available and 200 cars.
please guild me how to get  top10 model which highest in car table.
and get available car number for each top10 model.

or tell me the concept , do i need group by , count or something else?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It's helpful if other users can see some kind of code you've tried and see if they can help guide you based upon that.

Comment: Define "highest in car table" - TOP 10 car_id?

Comment: You're asking what models are "highest" but I am not sure how you are ranking "high." Would you be able to post your desired results? And also what SQL you have tried so far?

Comment: the most available car  . I am not very good english , Somebody can translate/explain for me?

Comment: example   There are 20 cars for model A  , 33 cars for model B  , 50 cars for model C , 11 car for model e  .The top3 model is C,B,A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic query to get the top 10 based on *counting* rows is:

```
-- SQL SERVER
select top 10 model_id
     , count(*) as qtyCars
  from cars
 group by model_id
 order by count(*) desc

-- Other servers
select model_id
     , count(*) as qtyCars
  from cars
 group by model_id
 order by count(*) desc
 LIMIT 10
```

**EDIT**: I don't normally push my own blog, but this post I wrote a few years ago consistently is my most popular going by search hits, and covers GROUP BY: http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/04/group-by-having-sum-avg-and-count.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're wanting to group them, so I just grouped them by their model_id

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM model JOIN car ON car.model_id = model.model_id GROUP BY car.model_id DESC
```